# Cron to move books?

Tags: recursion, cron, move

I am trying to get cron to move my books into a book folder automatically but it seems that it doesn't work recursively.

Here's the code:

```
find /mnt/Storage/Torrents/Completed -R -type f -name "*.epub" -exec mv {} /mnt/Storage/Books\;
```

Thanks!

Comment: This question made me laugh, i was thinking of physical books!

Comment: find is already recursive so you don't need -R (i'm not sure that's even a valid switch). I suspect what you're really asking for is the mv command to create relative paths under /mnt/Storage/Books ?